# Groupby some columns and compute maximum difference between a column and another column shifted

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Consider the following dataframe (see end of this answer for code to generate it):

```
    A         T0         T1
0   0 2017-01-02 2017-01-04
1   2 2017-01-02 2017-01-05
2   1 2017-01-03 2017-01-04
3   3 2017-01-04 2017-01-07
4   2 2017-01-07 2017-01-10
5   0 2017-01-08 2017-01-10
6   3 2017-01-08 2017-01-09
7   1 2017-01-10 2017-01-11
8   0 2017-01-11 2017-01-13
9   3 2017-01-12 2017-01-15
10  2 2017-01-13 2017-01-16
11  1 2017-01-15 2017-01-17
12  0 2017-01-18 2017-01-20
13  3 2017-01-19 2017-01-20
14  1 2017-01-20 2017-01-22
15  2 2017-01-20 2017-01-21
16  2 2017-02-03 2017-02-06
17  1 2017-02-03 2017-02-06
18  0 2017-02-04 2017-02-07
19  3 2017-02-05 2017-02-07
20  1 2017-02-07 2017-02-08
21  3 2017-02-09 2017-02-11
22  0 2017-02-09 2017-02-10
23  1 2017-02-13 2017-02-16
24  3 2017-02-15 2017-02-17
25  2 2017-02-15 2017-02-18
26  0 2017-02-17 2017-02-18
27  2 2017-02-19 2017-02-21
28  3 2017-02-20 2017-02-21
29  2 2017-02-24 2017-02-27
30  1 2017-02-25 2017-02-26
31  0 2017-02-27 2017-03-01
```

I want to group using a `pandas.Grouper` (e.g. by month) and on `A` and for each group `g` compute the maximum value of `g.T0 - g.T1.shift()`.

I am currently doing the following:

```
def fun(x):
    x['G'] = x.T0 - x.T1.shift()
    return x

u = df.groupby((pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='T0'), 'A')).apply(fun)
u = df.groupby((pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='T0'), 'A'))['G'].max()
```

This works but is **very** slow — My current dataframe contains ~80m lines and it takes more than 30 minutes to compute this for the group I want.

The expected output for the above data frame would be:

```
T0          A
2017-01-01  0   5 days
            1   6 days
            2   4 days
            3   4 days
2017-02-01  0   9 days
            1   9 days
            2   9 days
            3   4 days
Name: G, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I have tested another approach which consist in computing the gap before end:

```
df = df.sort_values(['A', 'T0'])
df['G'] = df.T0 - df.T1.shift()
df.loc[df['A'].diff() != 0, 'G'] = pd.NaT
```

Then I could simply:

```
df.groupby((pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='T0'), 'A'))['G'].max()
```

The problem here is that the first entry of each group is the gap between the current group and the previous one, so I get:

```
T0          A
2017-01-01  0    5 days
            1    6 days
            2    4 days
            3    4 days
2017-02-01  0   15 days
            1   12 days
            2   13 days
            3   16 days
Name: G, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

What I would need would be:

```
df.groupby((pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='T0'), 'A')).all_but_first()['G'].max()
```

The problem is that `all_but_first` does not exists in pandas.

Is there a way to either:

- Speed up the first code using `apply`;
- Compute for each group the maximum values, without regarding the first value for each group?

---

Code to generate the dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

A = np.repeat(range(4), 8)
T0 = [1, 7, 10, 17, 34, 39, 47, 57, 
      2, 9, 14, 19, 33, 37, 43, 55, 
      1, 6, 12, 19, 33, 45, 49, 54, 
      3, 7, 11, 18, 35, 39, 45, 50]
T1 = [3, 9, 12, 19, 37, 40, 48, 59, 
      3, 10, 16, 21, 36, 38, 46, 56, 
      4, 9, 15, 20, 36, 48, 51, 57, 
      6, 8, 14, 19, 37, 41, 47, 51]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'T0': T0, 'T1': T1})
df['T0'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T0'], unit='D', origin=pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01'))
df['T1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T1'], unit='D', origin=pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01'))
df = df.sort_values('T0')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: one more thing is to add the output you are getting while running your code. So we better understand the problem.

Comment: @Bharath I have update the question, added code to generate the data frame, expected output, and output I get with the "fast" version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['new'] = df['T0'].sub(df.groupby((pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='T0'), 'A'))['T1'].shift())
df = df.groupby((pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='T0'), 'A'))['new'].max()
print (df)
T0          A
2017-01-01  0   5 days
            1   6 days
            2   4 days
            3   4 days
2017-02-01  0   9 days
            1   9 days
            2   9 days
            3   4 days
Name: new, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

One idea is use `max` in `apply`:

```
u = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: (x.T0 - x.T1.shift()).max())
print (u)
A
0    4.0
1    6.0
2    5.0
3    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Or first subtract `shifted` column and then aggregate `max`:

```
df = df['T0'].sub(df.groupby(['A'])['T1'].shift()).groupby(df['A']).max()
print (df)
A
0    4.0
1    6.0
2    5.0
3    3.0
dtype: float64
```

EDIT by changed data:

```
df = df['T0'].sub(df.groupby(['A', 'V'])['T1'].shift()).groupby([df['A'], df['V']]).max()
print (df)
A  V    
0  False    4.0
   True     2.0
1  False    3.0
   True     4.0
2  False    1.0
   True     5.0
3  False    3.0
   True     3.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Sir there are  `~80 mil lines` apply is definitely not recommended, but second solution might be fast

Comment: I have no better solution now ;)

Comment: Thanks, I already tried the first solution but it was not much faster than my current one with apply... I will try the second one and let you know if it works  on the actual problem.

Comment: The second approach seems to works for the new example, but how would I do it if instead of grouping on a column `A` I wanted to use a custom grouper (e.g. `pd.Grouper(freq='AS', key='T0', label='left')`? Especially how would I replace the last `.groupby(df['A'])`?

Comment: @jezrael Yes I already tested this before posting the new example, the problem would be if instead of grouping on a column I wanted to group using a `pandas.Grouper`? I will try to update the example... It is hard to find a minimal dataframe for testing purpose :/

Comment: I think it should works like `df = df['T0'].sub(df.groupby([df['A'], pd.Grouper(freq='AS', key='T0', label='left')])['T1'].shift()).groupby([df['A'], pd.Grouper(freq='AS', key='T0', label='left')]).max()` - untested

Comment: @jezrael I have updated the example with actual datetime and code to generate the data frame, sorry to have not put that earlier... The code in your comment does not work because the second `groupie` does not find the `T0` key (`'The grouper name T0 is not found'`).

Comment: I edit answer, but get a bit different output for second group.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I could not try this sooner... The last version works perfectly and it gives me a huge speedup (~1500s -> ~80s). Maybe you should move it to the beginning of your answer? Anyway, thanks for your help!